# Force close on viewing database entries: Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In the android app I'm developing, I am storing an entry and then I want to view it. I am able to store the entry (the code does not return any errors) but when I try to view the entries (i.e. all entries) I get a force close. Please help me. Here's my code:

```
package com.ankita.try1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class viewAttendance extends Activity {

LinearLayout l;
quer q;
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_attendance);

        l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);

        q= new quer(this);
        q.open();
        Cursor c1;
        c1=q.fetchAllTodos();

        long co=1;

        if(c1!=null)
        {
            do
            {
                TextView t;

                Cursor c=q.fetchTodo(co);
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(quer.KEY_NAME));
                String present = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(quer.KEY_PRESENT));
                String total = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(quer.KEY_TOTAL));

                int a = (Integer.parseInt(present)/Integer.parseInt(total))*100;

                String A = a+"%";

                LayoutParams la=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                t=new TextView(this);
                t.setLayoutParams(la);
                t.setText(name+"   "+A);                                
                l.addView(t);
                co++;
            }while(co<=c1.getCount());
            q.close();
        }
        else
        {
            q.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Subjects Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



         }

}
```

Here is my quer.java (where all functions are defined):

```
package com.ankita.try1;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.ankita.try1.database1;

public class quer 
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_PRESENT = "present";
    public static final String KEY_ABSENT = "absent";
    public static final String KEY_TOTAL = "total";

    /*public static final int KEY_PRESENT=0;
    public static final int KEY_ABSENT=0;
    public static final int KEY_TOTAL=0;*/

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "SUBJECT";
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private database1 dbHelper;
    public quer(Context context) 
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public quer open() throws SQLException 
    {
        dbHelper = new database1(context);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        dbHelper.close();
    }
    private ContentValues createContentValues(String name, String present, String absent,String total) 
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        values.put(KEY_PRESENT, present);
        values.put(KEY_ABSENT, absent);
        values.put(KEY_TOTAL, total);
        return values;
    }
    //TO CREATE A ROW
    public long createTodo(String name, String present, String absent,String total) {
        ContentValues initialValues = createContentValues(name, present,absent,total);
                return database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
    //TOI DELETE A ROW
    public boolean deleteTodo(long rowId) 
    {
        return database.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
    //FETCH ALL ROWS
    public Cursor fetchAllTodos() 
    {
        return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME, KEY_PRESENT, KEY_ABSENT, KEY_TOTAL}, null, null, null,null, null);
    }
    //UPDATE THE DATABASE
    public boolean updateTodo(long rowId, String name, String present, String absent,String total) 
    {
        ContentValues updateValues = createContentValues(name, present,absent,total);
        return database.update(DATABASE_TABLE, updateValues, KEY_ROWID + "="
                + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
    //FETCH ACC. TO _ID
    public Cursor fetchTodo(long rowId) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PRESENT, KEY_ABSENT, KEY_TOTAL },
                KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
    //FETCH ACC. TO NAME
    public Cursor fetchTodo(String name) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PRESENT, KEY_ABSENT, KEY_TOTAL },
                KEY_NAME + "=" + name, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
}
```

I cannot view the database entries i.e. I don't see anything of viewAttendance Activity being executed - I get a force close - where am I going wrong?

Here is the logcat:

```
07-05 19:06:16.304: D/AndroidRuntime(29530): Shutting down VM
07-05 19:06:16.304: W/dalvikvm(29530): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ankita.try1/com.ankita.try1.viewAttendance}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at com.ankita.try1.viewAttendance.onCreate(viewAttendance.java:36)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
07-05 19:06:16.328: E/AndroidRuntime(29530):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: I just added that. Let me know if that helps!!

Comment: remember to access database in another thread diferent than main UI one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im moving this to answer since its a bit too long for a comment.
First access the database within a thread, you can use `AsyncTask`, `Threads` or `CursorLoaders`.

also to move through the cursor try using `cursor.moveToNext()` and instead of a do-while use a simple while and check if its not afterlast with:

```
while(!cursor.isAfterLast){
    cursor.moveToNext();
    //do-something
}
```

also where you have this:

```
c1=q.fetchAllTodos();

        long co=1;

        if(c1!=null)
        { //something }
```

you are checking that your cursor is not null but remember that your cursor can be empty and that might cause you a problem (wich i guess its the one you are having) 
so to fix it add a validation like:

```
if(c1!=null && c1.getCount()!=0) 
 { //something }
```

also to update your `View` you cannot do so within a non-UI thread so you will need a handler, a post or other methods. If you will use an `AsyncTask` I recommend you do this in your `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried the getCount() method - turns out, no entries are in the database. I think I need to have a look at that code now :) Thanks a mil!

Comment: just click on the transparent tick (checkmark) on my answer :)